# Is there a linux terminal command that lets you see the amount of data coming in to your tcp connections in real time?

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth, terminal

It would be something similar to `top`, where you see your cpu processes in real time. I'm not looking for a GUI like Wireshark to do it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) is cool and lightweight.

[image: iftop_ui]

[ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) is even cooler but web-based and uses a daemon.

Answer (score 21):

[IPTraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) is another common real-time bandwidth monitor on Linux
[IPTraf-ng](https://fedorahosted.org/iptraf-ng/) is a updated fork of IPTraf with ipv6 support

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, last I checked, iptraf doesn't support display of IPv6 connections.

Answer (score 10):

[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/), in case you need traffic analys per application - [darkstat](http://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/) also works (web frontend)

Answer (score 8):

Those give all detailed info in a ui-style. If you are looking for a much simplier one use:

```
vnstat -l
```

You'll get something like (realtime updates):

```
[user@host ~]$ vnstat -l

Monitoring em1...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:        4 kbit/s     5 p/s          tx:        4 kbit/s     3 p/s
```

The same command can be used to get daily/monthly/etc traffic reports.

Answer (score 7):

Two small utilities that do this are [tcptrack](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/tcptrack/) and [jnettop](http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/)

[image: tcptrack]

[image: jnettop]