# Is it possible to display realtime network utilization without third part tools in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a linux terminal command that lets you see the amount of data coming in to your tcp connections in real time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/445333/is-there-a-linux-terminal-command-that-lets-you-see-the-amount-of-data-coming-in)

I want to able to display realtime (or near realtime) network utilization without third part tools in Linux, e.g.

102KB on interface eth0

is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "third party tools" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu it is shown in `ifconfig`, where `RX`: *Received*, `TX`: *Transmitted*

```
ifconfig eth0

eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:23:e3:50:0c  
      inet addr:192.168.2.14  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4074454586 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
      TX packets:2709815673 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2484134569 (2.4 GB)  TX bytes:978423284 (978.4 MB)
      Interrupt:41 Base address:0x7c00
```

To get just the usage, use `grep`:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX bytes'

RX bytes:2484134569 (2.4 GB)  TX bytes:978423284 (978.4 MB)
```

To continuously monitor, use `watch`:

`watch "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX bytes'"`

Answer (score 0):

There's `iftop` and `iptraf` to name but two.

> "iftop does for network usage what top(1) does for CPU usage"
>   -- http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/

Answer (score 0):

According to your Description, you want vnstat.

Question has also been answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/445333/is-there-a-linux-terminal-command-that-lets-you-see-the-amount-of-data-coming-in/445342)

Answer (score 0):

There is also `ifstat` if all you want is total throughput.